# Determining range of extreme points with linear constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, computational-geometry

I have a set defined by a lot of linear constraints. Namely, $\mathcal{X}=\{x:Ax\leq b\}$, where $x$ is a $j$- dimensional vector (each component can be either positive or negative). I want to know for each component $j$, $\bar x_j=\max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_j$ and $\underline x_j=\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_j$. I know that if I can enumerate all vertices, then I can simply take the minimum and maximum. But I wonder if there are better ways. Any hint is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumeration can be extremely expensive, so unless there is some particular structure in your case, the most efficient way is in general to solve $2j$ linear programs where you maximize and minimize along all directions.

Comment: We can do it by just solving only one LP ! instead of solving $2n$ problems

Answer (score 1):

By Solving Just one LP you can find those lower and upper bounds

$$ \begin{align}
  \max & \sum_{j} (\bar{y}^j _{j} - \underline y_{j} ^j)\\ &\text{subject to}
\\
  &  \bar{y}^j  \in \mathcal{X} &j=1,2...,n   \\
  & \underline y_{} ^j  \in \mathcal{X} &j=1,2...,n
\end{align} $$

DONE.

PS. The optimal solution of this problem is

$$ (\bar x_1, \bar x_2,...\bar x_n, \underline x_1, \underline x_2,...,\underline x_n   ) \in \mathcal{X} ^2 $$

Comment: You're effectively encoding and solving the standard $2j$ linear programs using much more memory. As linear programming has linear or higher complexity w.r.t the number of variables and constraints, you are not going to save any time, but waste memory.